# Circle Collider Vibrates on Edge Collider

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I am making a game (kind of bricks) and using edge collider objects as world bounds collider. I am increasing count of balls on each iteration, after 5 balls, balls start to vibrate when they contact with edge colliders. Vibrating means, they do not bounce directly when they contact with edge collider, they vibrate on x axis for some period while they are moving upwards on y axis.

Ball physics: (friction is 0, bounciness is 1)
[image: Physics Attributes of ball]

Wall physics: (friction is 0, bounciness is 0)
[image: Physics attributes of walls]

I am not updating transform of ball object, directly set a velocity to balls.

Also i've recorded a video for this behavior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-bjkXZjXjs&feature=emb_logo

Which point i am missing on this setup? Can you help me to solve this problem?

Best,

Edit:

I have a input listener class, that updates BallThrowHandler.thrown variable, when you put your finger to screen, move and release.

Code that adds velocity to balls (which is running on another object):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BallContainerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
/// <summary>
/// total speed of the balls
/// </summary>
public float totalSpeed = 5f;

public float timeBetweenBalls = 0.2f;

WaitForSeconds wait;

public float degrees = 0f;

Rigidbody2D childBody;
Vector3 speedVector;

float cosinus;
float sinus;

void Start()
{
    wait = new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenBalls);
}


void Update()
{
    if(BallThrowHandler.thrown)
    {
        //start throw animation


        startBallMovement();
    }
}

// start ball movement if they thrown
private void startBallMovement()
{
    calculateDegrees();

    //speedUpBalls();

    if(BallThrowHandler.thrown)
    {
        StartCoroutine("speedUpBalls");
    }


    CollectBallHandler.CollectingBallsStarted = false;
    BallThrowHandler.BricksMovedDown = false;
}

private void calculateDegrees()
{
    degrees = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.right, BallThrowHandler.ThrowVector) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
}

private IEnumerator speedUpBalls()
{
    cosinus = Mathf.Cos(degrees);
    sinus = Mathf.Sin(degrees);

    speedVector = new Vector3(totalSpeed * cosinus, totalSpeed * sinus, 0f);

    foreach (Transform go in transform)
    {
        childBody = go.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        childBody.velocity = speedVector;
        yield return wait;
    }
    BallThrowHandler.thrown = false;
}}
```

And here is whole code for a ball object: (only bottom collider is trigger, left right and top is not)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BallEndTurnBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody2D body;

public float ballMinY;

public GameObject bricksContainer;

private BrickSpawner brickSpawner;
private BrickTurnOverMover brickTurnOverMover;

private const float EPSILON = 0.01f;



private void Awake()
{
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Start()
{
    brickSpawner = bricksContainer.GetComponent<BrickSpawner>();
    brickTurnOverMover = bricksContainer.GetComponent<BrickTurnOverMover>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if(System.Math.Abs(body.velocity.x) < EPSILON && System.Math.Abs(body.velocity.y) < EPSILON && CollectBallHandler.CollectingBallsStarted)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, CollectBallHandler.CollectingBallsPoint, 0.1f);
    }
}


private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (!CollectBallHandler.CollectingBallsStarted)
    {
        CollectBallHandler.CollectingBallsStarted = true;
        CollectBallHandler.CollectingBallsPoint = transform.position;
        CollectBallHandler.CollectingBallsPoint.y = ballMinY;
    }
    body.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);


    Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, CollectBallHandler.CollectingBallsPoint, 1f);

    if(!BallThrowHandler.BricksMovedDown)
    {
        brickTurnOverMover.moveBricks();
        BallThrowHandler.BricksMovedDown = true;
        brickSpawner.spawn();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to control the balls? That bounce looks rather unusual.

Comment: Added the code to question.

Comment: Can you show us where the `degrees` variable is set / updated, and when that coroutine is fired?

Comment: There is a LineRenderer object, that sets vector to BallThrowHandler.ThrowVector.

Comment: Hmmm... Sounds like there's some work to be done to boil this question down to a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: a set of instructions and code snippets sufficient for a reader to reproduce the problem in a new, empty project, without needing back-and-forth clarifications in the comments. Can you try to produce such a minimal example and update your question with the complete recipe?

Comment: But the weirdest part is, this is not happening with 1 or 2 or 3 balls. It usually starts after 5 or 6 balls.

Comment: I am working on reproducing the issue currently, i am going to share the minimal reproduced issue.

Comment: Probably i found the issue. Talking with you enlightened me! I was looking for an explanation for 2 days. I removed coroutine staff from code, and it is working correctly. I think its about foreach loop's behavior with waiting code i've written. I am going to try different approach to setup some time difference between balls.

Comment: Happy to be a rubber duck if it's useful to you! :) You may want to edit your question to something along the lines of "why does this coroutine lead to this vibration" or "how can I speed up my balls without vibration" or something like that, based on your new discovery.